# GraphQL Clojure: Getting the GQL query fields

Tags: server, clojure, graphql, schema, resolver

I'm using [lacinia](https://lacinia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library for my GraphQL Clojure server.
For this simple schema:

```
input QueryConfig {
  startDate: String!
  endDate: String!
}


type MyData{
  x: Float!
  y: Float!
  z: Float!
}

schema {
    query: Query
}

type Query {
  myQuery(config:QueryConfig) : [MyData]
}
```

I'm posting the following query:

```
{
  myQuery(config:{startDate:"2020-01-01",endDate:"2020-01-01"}){
    x
  }
}
```

In my resolver code, I would like to know what fields were asked (x in the example above), So I won't over fetch results from my DB and retrieve **only** the x values.

In the resolver code the context contains **:graphql-query** key which contains the entire query. However, parsing the query text seems awkward.

```
(defn my-resolver
  [context args value]
  ;TODO find out what fields were asked and fetch from DB
  )
```

What would be the right way of getting the query fields?

Answer (score 1):

Lacinia does allow you to preview nested selections:

> A field resolver can “preview” what fields will be selected below it
>   in the selections tree. This is a tool frequently used to optimize
>   data retrieval operations.

Example code from [docs](https://lacinia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/selections.html#previewing-selections):

```clj
(require
  '[com.walmartlabs.lacinia.executor :as executor])

(defn resolve-hero
  [context args _]
  (if (executor/selects-field? context :character/friends)
    (fetch-hero-with-friends args)
    (fetch-hero args)))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://lacinia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/selections.html):

> It is also possible to get all the fields that will be selected, using
>   selections-seq. This a lazy, breadth-first navigation of all fields in
>   the selection tree.

So you can use: `(executor/selections-seq context)` to get all fields that were sent by the query.